# add REF in JSX only if it is not null

Tags: reactjs

I am new using react.

I'd like to add REF in my component only if it is not null.

```
  if (posts.length === index + 1) {
        number = post.id;
        return <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} ref={lastPostElementRef} titulo={post.titulo} />
    }
    else {
        return <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} titulo={post.titulo} />
    }
```

if it is the last `post` it should add a ref on it. The others will not got this ref val.

so I try:

```
const Post = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (

    <div 
        className={classes.post} 

//if (ref != null) ???
        ref={ref} >

        data-id: {props.id}
        titulo: {props.titulo}

    </div>

));

export default Post;
```

how can I check if ref is not null inside my JSX to add or not the ref={ref} value inside my div?

Comment: This will work correctly without any changes.

Comment: @Sulthan shouldnt I check if ref is null or not?

Comment: No, there is no need to check whether forwarded ref is `null` or not. In other words, `null` is the default value.

Answer (score 1):

If no ref is passed to your Post component, then ref would just be undefined, so the div's you don't want to get ref, will get `ref={undefined}`. This works as you want it to.

However, you can also explicitly check for the ref in a ternary operator: `ref ? ref : undefined` or `ref != null ? ref : undefined`, but that is just longer than it has to be (unnecessary).

PS: You don't want to explicitly check for `null` because you never set the ref to be `null`, but you also don't want to use the `!=` operator as that will implicitly convert undefined into null. When comparing in javascript, you should use `!==` or `===`, but then it won't be `true` when ref is undefined, because undefined won't be converted into null. In a way, your intended syntax is doing 2 things poorly which gives you the intended outcome.

More info on `===` vs `==` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).